# Validate unique value from database in Yii2

Tags: yii2

I am trying to validate email value as unique value. Doing it like this.

```
[['HRMS_candidateEmail'],'unique'],
```

But it is not working, inserted statement `use yii\validators\UniqueValidator;`,  following this [link](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-validators-uniquevalidator.html)

Model

```
<?php
namespace app\models;
 use Yii;
 use yii\validators\UniqueValidator;


 class Candidate extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
 {
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public static function tableName()
{
    return 'HRMS_candidate';
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['HRMS_candidateEmail'],'unique'],
        [['HRMS_candidateFirstName', 'HRMS_candidateLastName', 'HRMS_candidateEmail', 'HRMS_candidateMobileNo', 'HRMS_candidateLocalAddress', 'HRMS_candidatePermanantAddress',  'HRMS_candidateGender', 'HRMS_candidateDateOfBirth',
          'HRMS_candidateMaritalStatus',  'HRMS_candidaterRefType', 'HRMS_candidateStatus',  'HRMS_candidateCurrentSalary', 'HRMS_candidateExpectedSalary', 'HRMS_candidateNoticePeriodBuyOut',  'HRMS_candidateCountry', 'HRMS_candidateCity',
           'HRMS_candidatePrimarySkills', 'HRMS_candidateWillingToRelocate','HRMS_candidateExpYears','HRMS_candidateExpMonths','HRMS_candidateHrId','HRMS_candidateNoticePeriod','HRMS_candidateResumeSource',
           'HRMS_candidateTrack','HRMS_candidateDepartment','HRMS_candidateNoOfChildren'], 'required'],
        [['HRMS_candidateGender', 'HRMS_candidateBloodGroup', 'HRMS_candidateMaritalStatus', 'HRMS_candidaterRefType', 'HRMS_candidateStatus'], 'string'],
        [['HRMS_candidateDateOfBirth',   'HRMS_candidateCreatedAt', 'HRMS_candidateUpdatedAt'], 'safe'],
        [['HRMS_candidateTokenNo', 'HRMS_candidateNoticePeriodBuyOut', 'HRMS_candidateExpYears','HRMS_candidateExpMonths', 'HRMS_candidateNoOfChildren','HRMS_candidateMobileNo','HRMS_candidateAlternateNo','HRMS_candidateAdharNumber','HRMS_candidateNoticePeriod'], 'integer'],
        [['HRMS_candidateFirstName', 'HRMS_candidateMiddleName', 'HRMS_candidateLastName', 'HRMS_candidateCurrentSalary', 'HRMS_candidateExpectedSalary'], 'string', 'max' => 50],
        [['HRMS_candidateEmail', 'HRMS_candidateAlternateEmail'], 'string', 'max' => 150],
        [['HRMS_candidateMobileNo', 'HRMS_candidateAlternateNo', 'HRMS_candidatePanNumber', 'HRMS_candidateAdharNumber'], 'string', 'max' => 25],
        [['HRMS_candidateLocalAddress', 'HRMS_candidatePermanantAddress'], 'string', 'max' => 500],
        [['HRMS_candidateNoticePeriod'], 'string', 'max' => 10],
        [['HRMS_candidatePrimarySkills'], 'string', 'max' => 300],
        [['HRMS_candidateEmail','HRMS_candidateAlternateEmail'], 'email'],            
        [['HRMS_candidateFirstName','HRMS_candidateMiddleName','HRMS_candidateLastName'], 'match', 'pattern' => '/^[a-zA-Z]+$/', 'message' => 'Please enter alphabets only.'],
        [['HRMS_candidatePanNumber'], 'match', 'pattern' => '/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/', 'message' => 'Please enter alphanumric charachters only.'],
        [['HRMS_candidatePassportNo','HRMS_candidateCountry','HRMS_candidateCity'], 'match', 'pattern' => '/^[a-zA-Z0-9-_@ ]+$/', 'message' => 'Please enter alphanumric charachters only.'],
        [['HRMS_candidateLocalAddress','HRMS_candidatePermanantAddress'], 'match', 'pattern' => '/^[a-zA-Z0-9-_@.,: ]+$/', 'message' => 'Please enter valid address.'],
        [['HRMS_candidatePrimarySkills'], 'match', 'pattern' => '/^[a-zA-Z0-9-_@.#+&*, ]+$/', 'message' => 'Please enter valid skills.'],
        [['HRMS_candidateAlternateEmail'], 'compare', 'compareAttribute' => 'HRMS_candidateEmail','operator'=>'!='],
        [['HRMS_candidateAlternateNo'], 'compare', 'compareAttribute' => 'HRMS_candidateMobileNo','operator'=>'!='],

    ];
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'HRMS_candidateID' => 'ID',
        'HRMS_candidateReferralID' => 'Referral ID',
        'HRMS_candidateFirstName' => 'First Name',
        'HRMS_candidateMiddleName' => 'Middle Name',
        'HRMS_candidateLastName' => 'Last Name',
        'HRMS_candidateEmail' => 'E-mail Id',
        'HRMS_candidateAlternateEmail' => 'Alternate E-mail Id',
        'HRMS_candidateMobileNo' => 'Mobile No',
        'HRMS_candidateAlternateNo' => 'Alternate No',
        'HRMS_candidateLocalAddress' => 'Current Address',
        'HRMS_candidatePermanantAddress' => 'Permanant Address',
        'HRMS_candidatePanNumber' => 'Pan Number',
        'HRMS_candidateAdharNumber' => 'Adhar Number',
        'HRMS_candidateGender' => 'Gender',
        'HRMS_candidateDateOfBirth' => 'Date Of Birth',
        'HRMS_candidateBloodGroup' => 'Blood Group',
        'HRMS_candidateMaritalStatus' => 'Marital Status',
        'HRMS_candidateNoOfChildren' => 'No Of Children',
        'HRMS_candidaterRefType' => 'Reference Type',
        'HRMS_candidateStatus' => 'Status',
        'HRMS_candidateTokenNo' => 'Token No',
        'HRMS_candidateRolesResponsibility' => 'Roles Responsibility',
        'HRMS_candidateTokenExpiryDate' => 'Token Expiry Date',
        'HRMS_candidateTokenGenerationDate' => 'Token Generation Date',
        'HRMS_candidateCurrentSalary' => 'Current Salary',
        'HRMS_candidateExpectedSalary' => 'Expected Salary',
        'HRMS_candidateNoticePeriod' => 'Notice Period',
        'HRMS_candidateNoticePeriodBuyOut' => 'Notice Period Buy Out',
        'HRMS_candidatePassportNo' => 'Passport No',
        'HRMS_candidateCountry' => 'Current Country',
        'HRMS_candidateCity' => 'Current City',
        'HRMS_candidatePrimarySkills' => 'Primary Skills',
        'HRMS_candidateExpYears' => 'Exp Years',
        'HRMS_candidateExpMonths'=> 'Exp Months',
        'HRMS_candidateWillingToRelocate' => 'Willing To Relocate',
        'HRMS_candidateDriveId' => 'Drive ID',
        'HRMS_candidateHrId' => 'HR Name',
        'HRMS_candidateCreatedAt' => 'Created At',
        'HRMS_candidateUpdatedAt' => 'Updated At',
        'HRMS_candidateResumeSource'=> 'Resume Source',
        'HRMS_candidateTrack'=>'Track',
        'HRMS_candidateDepartment'=>'Department',
        'HRMS_candidateVacancyId'=>'Vacancy'
    ];
}

/**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */


/**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getHRMSCandidateEducations()
{
    return $this->hasMany(HRMSCandidateEducation::className(), ['HRMS_candidateEducationCandidateID' => 'HRMS_candidateID']);
}

/**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getHRMSCandidateNotes()
{
    return $this->hasMany(HRMSCandidateNote::className(), ['HRMS_candidateNoteCandidateId' => 'HRMS_candidateID']);
}

/**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getHRMSCandidatePreviousEmployments()
{
    return $this->hasMany(HRMSCandidatePreviousEmployment::className(), ['HRMS_candidatePreviousEmploymentcandidateID' => 'HRMS_candidateID']);
}

/**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getHRMSFeedbacks()
{
    return $this->hasMany(HRMSFeedback::className(), ['HRMS_feedbackCandidateID' => 'HRMS_candidateID']);
}

/**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getHRMSInterviewSchedules()
{
    return $this->hasMany(HRMSInterviewSchedule::className(), ['HRMS_interviewScheduleCandidateID' => 'HRMS_candidateID']);
}

/**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getHRMSVacancyCandidates()
{
    return $this->hasMany(HRMSVacancyCandidate::className(), ['HRMS_vacancyCandidateCandiateID' => 'HRMS_candidateID']);
}

public static function getFull_Name()
    {
            return $this->HRMS_candidateFirstName . ' ' . $this->HRMS_candidateLastName;
    }
 }
```

view

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'HRMS_candidateEmail')->textInput(['maxlength' => true,'class'=>'form-control input-sm','placeholder'=>'Enter email of candidate']) ?>
```

Comment: Please be a little bit more specific on the "not working" part. Any errors?

Comment: @tarleb There is no error it accepts value which inserted before.

Comment: Are the other validations in the form working as expected?

Comment: Yes other validations are working well.

Comment: Show your model, then.  There is too little info do debug this in its current form.

Comment: make sure you have `unique index` for `candidate_email` in database.

Comment: show your view. I think you missing one thing there. Can you please show your view.

Comment: @NanaPartykar nana view add kelaye bagha

Comment: Hi Mr @Piyush : I have updated my answer. Please have a look. I don't have code your controller. Just add controller code and see whether it works or not. And, please let me know. Thanks. Jai Maharashtra.

Comment: @NanaPartykar Done:  Jai Maharashtra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming Your View as `register.php`. So,

**register.php (View)**

1) Remove `use yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm;` (if present)

2) Add `use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;`

3) Add `'enableAjaxValidation' => true` in that field (Where you are validating it. Like below)

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'HRMS_candidateEmail',['enableAjaxValidation' => true])->textInput(['maxlength' => true,'class'=>'form-control input-sm','placeholder'=>'Enter email of candidate']) ?>
```

**Controller**
Add these lines on top `use yii\web\Response;use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;`

```
use yii\web\Response;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;

    .
    .
    .
  public function actionRegister() {

         $model = new Candidate();

         //Add This For Ajax Email Exist Validation 
         if(Yii::$app->request->isAjax && $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())){
           Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
           return ActiveForm::validate($model);
         } 

         else if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            .
            // Your code
            .
            .
         }
  }
```